# E-mail for order Button in stead if Add to Cart

Tags: orders, forms

for some products we want to replace the add to cart button with a "Email to Order" button.

I will use an alternative theme for this.

I know how to disable the "Add to cart button".

But now i would like to have a button "Mail to order"

And when the customers clicks on this button, a small form shows up with the ability to fill in their name and e-mailadress.

And we get an email with their contactdata and the product they want to order (automatically) with the selected configurable option.

Is that possible, and how do i do that?

I use magento 1.8.1 CE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do some customization for your requirements.

This will give give you some hint.

Copy

**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml**

to your theme

**app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml**

in this file you can add some condition for your requirement

**For example,**

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php $mailToOrder = $this->__('Mail to order'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if(/*put your condotion*/); ?>

            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $mailToOrder ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="showCustomForm();"><span><span><?php echo $mailToOrder ?></span></span></button>

        <?php else: ?>

            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>

    </div>
<?php endif; ?>


<script>

    function showCustomForm()
    {
        // you can open popup or display form as per your requirement.
    }

</script>
```